# Getting time taken for each thread

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am checking a load with a minimum of 2000 threads in JMeter in the command line mode. I am using Graphic Generator also to get nice graphs. But at the end of the execution, I am getting an aggregated result inside the graphics generated results. What I actually wanted is the time taken for each thread in a nice format either in CSV or in Graph.

The command I am using is

```
sh jmeter -n -t /Project/Tests/test.jmx -l /Project/Tests/results.csv
```

Even though the results.CSV generates the whole but its not in a nice format. Can someone suggest me any other better options if available? Because my program is expecting each thread to return within 7 seconds if not my program will discard that thread. Hence i need to know how many threads are returned within 7 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should already have what you need.

1. You can figure out threads response times from .jtl results file, look into `elapsed` column. You can sort and see the most time-consuming sample results and how many of them exceed 7000 ms

   [image: JMeter CSV Sort]
2. There is [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) graph which can show the trend of response times while the test is running

   [image: JMeter Response Times Over Time]
3. There is [Response Times Distribution](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimesDistribution/) graph which can show the statistics of response times per number of requests executed

   [image: JMeter Response Times distribution]

   Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
4. And finally you can use [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) so JMeter would fail requests which last longer than 7 seconds automatically

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Which plug in from the Plug in manager will install the above 2 plug ins?